# instagram - get media from people you follow with private profile

Tags: instagram, python-3.3

I am using Instagram's [User Endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) in an attempt to retrieve media from people who I'm following.
I have a sandbox working with other members of my team, with each of us following the others.
I have authenticated myself through the server-side flow as indicated [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) and retrieved a list of ids of the people I follow (namely the members of my team) via the [Relationship Endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/).
In trying to get user media for those ids, however, I receive:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot view this resource"}}
```

Indicating an error because they have private profiles.
Is there anyway getting around this, seeing as I am actually an approved follower?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with the new Instagram API, I think they are getting rid of this feature